# Input type='file' accept pdf and excel file extension

Tags: javascript, file, validation, input

I want an input `type="file"` to accept only pdf and excel

I did this `<input type="file" name="upload" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel" />`

And it accepts .pdf and .xls files, but not .xlsx, how can I make it accept xlsx files as well?

Comment: Can't you just do `accept=".pdf, .xls"`?

Comment: Have you tried other MIME types for `xlsx`? A quick google search suggested `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Here is a format list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Limiting_accepted_file_types

Comment: @LizParody, Didn't want to be rude, it was just straight forward. Sorry, if you felt other way. Just for the next time sake, you can try searching for "file input html" or something like it, the MDN or w3c links should give you good examples for basic functionalities. 
Again, don't take it otherwise. Give it a good try yourself, before asking help, would help you in long run

Comment: @FissureKing, "input type=file", the first link of search should help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try following:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

In modern browser you can also use file extensions directly like:

```
accept=".pdf, .xls, .xlsx"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this and let me know !

```
   <input type="file" accept=".pdf,.xls" />
```

**EDIT** 
Simply

```
<input type="file" accept="add all the extension of your choice separating by a comma " />
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I did this: `accept=".pdf, .xls, .xlsx"`  and it worked ;)